# Connect PHP to Postgresql using PDO and new user

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I want to connect to a PostgreSQL database using PDO object here is what I did:

For **Postgres**

```
CREATE USER testdb_login WITH PASSWORD 'abcd';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE testdb TO testdb_login;
```

In **PHP**

```
$conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb", "testdb_login", "abcd");
```

The above code gives me a fatal error:

```
Call to a member function fetch() on boolean...
```

BUT if I try the same code with default username

```
 $conn = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb", "postgres", "password");
```

I can connect successfully and retrieve the data.

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Check what returns `$conn->errorInfo();` It will tell more about what is the problem.

Comment: This is the error "ERROR: permission denied for relation userinfo"

Comment: What is the exact query on which you call fetch?

Comment: There is a table in database testdb named userinfo, it contains 3 columns id(serial), name(varchar) and age(smallint).

The query I used is this
"SELECT name, age FROM userinfo WHERE id=1";

Comment: Also there are 4-5 entries in the table, so it won't return blank data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA testdb TO testdb_login;
```

If testdb is also the schema name in which the userinfo table is.

Comment: The schema is public, still I tried the above with testdb replaced with public but won't work.

Comment: Got it. permission need to be granted on the table itself and not the database.